# Submit form works fine in Firefox but not Safari

Tags: javascript, forms, wordpress, firefox, safari

I have added a Javascript code to my message system. This JS code adds a line of BBCode in the textarea when user clicks on the submit button.

The BBCode gets inserted fine in both Firefox and Safari. However, the message only goes through in Firefox. When posting with Safari, it does not go through to the database. I have only tested this with these two browsers, it is likely that it is broken with others.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Start javascript code for message type -->
<script>
    var messageType = {
        General: "[b][green]General[/green]:[/b]",
        News: "[b][blue]News[/blue]:[/b]",
        Trend: "[b][orange]Trend[/orange]:[/b]",
        Help: "[b][red]Help[/red]:[/b]"
    };

    function submitForm(){
        msgSelText = messageType [document.getElementById('messageSelection').value]
        document.getElementById('wpam_nm_text').value = msgSelText + ' ' +document.getElementById('wpam_nm_text').value;
        document.getElementById('new_post_form').submit();
    }
</script>
<!-- End javascript code for message type -->

<form name="new_post" method="post" action="admin.php?page=wp-admin-microblog/wp-admin-microblog.php" id="new_post_form">
    <table class="widefat">
        <thead>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="postdiv" class="postarea" style="display:block;">
                    <textarea name="wpam_nm_text" id="wpam_nm_text" style="width:100%;" rows="4"></textarea>
                </div>
                Type of message:
                <select id="messageSelection">
                    <option>General</option>
                    <option>News</option>
                    <option>Trend</option>
                    <option>Help</option>
                </select>

                <p style="text-align:right; float:right;"><input name="send" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Send', 'wp_admin_blog'); ?>" onclick="submitForm()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</form>
```

I removed the Javascript code and the form worked fine in Safari. This means that somehow, the JS code is making it not function - **why**? **And how do I fix it**?

Comment: any error messages in the Error Console off the safari develop menu?

Comment: I see you are missing a ; on the msgSelText line. Sometimes the js interpreter gets confused.

Comment: No - no errors. On which line? I believe that I have the ; correct on the msgSelText line?

Comment: the 9th line inside the `<script>`. Not sure it's a problem but it's good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the god forsaken thing by completely rewriting the javascript code, now works fine in both browsers. I have no idea what was wrong with the original approach, not entirely impossible that it was a browser bug.

Here is the new approach:

```
<!-- Start javascript code for message type -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function setText(){
  var messageType = document.getElementById('messageType');
   var feed = document.getElementById('feed');
    feed.value= messageType.value + " "  +
    feed.value;
    }
</script>
<!-- End javascript code for message type -->

<form name="new_post" method="post" action="admin.php?page=wp-admin-microblog/wp-admin-microblog.php" id="new_post_form">
    <table class="widefat">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php _e('Your Message', 'wp_admin_blog');?><a name="newpost"></a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="postdiv" class="postarea" style="display:block;">
                    <textarea name="wpam_nm_text" id="feed" style="width:100%;" rows="4"></textarea>
                </div>
                Type of message:

                 <select id="messageType" style="width:100px; height:20px; text-align:center;">
                     <option value="[b][green]General[/green]:[/b]">General</option>
                     <option value="[b][blue]News[/blue]:[/b]">News</option>
                     <option value="[b][orange]Trend[/orange]:[/b]">Trend</option>
                     <option value="[b][red]Help[/red]:[/b]">Help</option>
                </select>

                <p style="text-align:right; float:right;"><input name="send" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Send', 'wp_admin_blog'); ?>" onclick="javascript:setText()" /></p>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Safari, I'm getting a Reference Error when I run this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/esCPN/1/

If you are going to use `onclick` to trigger javascript evens (which you shouldn't) then you should use the `javascript:` syntax.

```
<input name="send" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Send"
    onclick="javascript:submitForm()" />
```

This will stop any Reference Errors that Safari is throwing.

Comment: I just replaced my code with your fix, but it did not solve it. Again, it works perfectly in Firefox but post does not come through in Safari. Any other ideas?

Comment: The post does not appear on the Admin page? Or the form submit does not fire?

Comment: The post does not appear on admin page.

Comment: However, as I mentioned earlier, if I remove the javascript addition to the form, then everything works perfect in Safari. This is turning into a bizarre puzzle...

Comment: Does safari give you any console output at all? Maybe try some `console.log`s to give you an idea where the breakdown is.

Comment: No, it did give me a very minor warning which I fixed. It did not resolve this problem though. Any further ideas?

Comment: yeah put a `console.log("TEST")` inside your `submitForm` function. If it shows in the console, then the function fired at least.

Comment: I added it to the function and I could see that *TEST* appeared when submitting. So this means that the function fires...? Why doesn't post appear in admin page then?

Comment: Yes the function fired. Now, move the console.log down one line, and see if it shows again. Rinse, repeat until you find the line that doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I added the console line after **document.getElementById('new_post_form').submit();**

Comment: Stumped. Try a different Safari version and make sure it's not a browser bug.

Comment: I am running the very latest version of Safari and I highly doubt it is a browser issue. Nonetheless, thank you very much for you effort.

Comment: I finally solved the damn thing. I made a completely different approach to the javascript code and it worked, I have posted an answer, you can have a look if you are interested. I have upvoted your answer regardless as it was somewhat helpful.